# How to get dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an element animation, for this I need to take the height of the previous element `[.as-body-wrap]` and use it in styles as the indent from the top for the element below `[.as-toaster.is_open]`

Here is my HTML and jQuery:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  const cta = document.querySelector('.as_header');
  const footer = document.querySelector('.as-toaster');
  const expandIcon = document.querySelector('.expand_icon');
  const asheight = document.querySelector('.as-body-wrap').offsetHeight;

  function toggleFooter() {
    footer.classList.toggle('is_open');
    expandIcon.classList.toggle('is_reversed')
  }

  cta.addEventListener('click', toggleFooter);

  // onclick action not the best implementation
  $(cta).toggle(
    function() {
      $('.as-toaster.is_open').css('margin-top', -asheight);
    },
    function() {
      $('.as-toaster').css('margin-top', '');
    }
  );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="as-body-wrap">
    <h3 class="as-title">Hi! I am Andrey</h3>
    <p class="as-sub-title">fashion designer</p>
    <div class="as-description">
      <p>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="as-toaster">
    <div class="as-wrapper">
      <header class="as_header">
        <div class="as-contact">Contact Me</div>
        <div class="as-contact-info">Please send me an email by filling out the form below.</div>
        <svg class="expand_icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M16.59 8.59L12 13.17 7.41 8.59 6 10l6 6 6-6z"></path>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
   </svg>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Next is add style to `.as-toaster.is_open` margin-top: -`.as-body-wrap` height

it looks like this line,

```
$('.as-toaster.is_open').css('margin-top', - asheight);
```

but how to get this height dinamocally in case this height can change when viewed in landscape mode

Comment: Could you also provide the CSS for this page?

Comment: $(...).parent()

Comment: there is a working example, but the problem is the same http://www.ub.asatechnology.com.ua/news-list/ right sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you just need a way to get the height of the `.as-body-wrap` div before running the animation.

This can be done using jQuery's [height function](http://api.jquery.com/height/):

```
$(".as-body-wrap").height();
```

This will return the current computed height of the selected element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  const cta = document.querySelector('.as_header');
  const footer = document.querySelector('.as-toaster');
  const expandIcon = document.querySelector('.expand_icon');
  let asBody = $(".as-body-wrap");
  let asheight = 0;

  function setASBodyHeight() {
    asheight = asBody.height();
    console.log(`Set asheight to ${asheight}`);
  }

  function toggleFooter() {
    footer.classList.toggle('is_open');
    expandIcon.classList.toggle('is_reversed')
  }

  cta.addEventListener('click', toggleFooter);

  setASBodyHeight();
  $(window).resize(setASBodyHeight);

  // onclick action not the best implementation
  $(cta).toggle(
    function() {
      let asheight = $('.as-body-wrap').height();
      $('.as-toaster.is_open').css('margin-top', -asheight);
    },
    function() {
      $('.as-toaster').css('margin-top', '');
    }
  );

});
```

Comment: that's right, I need the height and your example works, but as soon as the width of this block changes, you need to take the height again.

Comment: When does the width of this block change? On a window resize or some other event?

Comment: On a window resize

Comment: it turns out that if the height of the block has changed you need to update it in our variable asheight

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a function that sets the `asheight` variable. I have also added a line that adds an event listener for when the window is resized. This listener function will set the `asheight` variable to the current computed height.

Comment: cool, it works! but you can make it so that the height is updated constantly and when you click, the function on the styles is triggered

Comment: yet the best way is to change the margin-top in parallel when changing the height and not just by clicking. Is it possible?